# embed loc. data on each frame while recording via camerax in android

Tags: android, kotlin, ffmpeg, video-processing

I'm trying to **embed the location** data into **every frame** of **video** while recording from camerax, but unable to achieve that.

> However, Overall location embedding is done by simply writing an Exif
> to the whole video.

But how can we achieve the location/other data for every frame of a video in android kotlin?

Comment: EXIF is for static images, not video. Please clarify are you trying to embed metadata in the video stream OR put text of the location within the video image as the video plays.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. <br> Yes I'm trying to embed metadata in the video stream while rec.

Comment: To my knowledge video only has one metadata section. See: [Android: Read and Write .mp4 metadata -Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36956668/295004)